# How to express "instead of on the condition that "?

Tags: conjunctions

> James said yesterday that he may go to the party on the condition that the
>   party is free of charge. Today, however, he says that he may go to the
>   party on the condition that Charlotte goes to the party with him **instead of on the condition that the party is free of charge.**

I think the usage "instead of on the condition that" in the sentence above I created is improper because I could not find such usage on the Internet.  I feel that simply using "instead" may be OK, but I would like to use the full sentence "the party is free of charge".

Comment: These phrases are very formal.  I would expect them in [legalese](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/legalese/info).  They are not natural in informal gossip.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to find more graceful or less wordy ways to phrase this, but there's nothing truly wrong with it. The usage of "instead of on the condition that" is not improper.

If you wanted to be really stodgy (and a bit obsolete), you could argue that "on the condition that" requires the present subjunctive, so it could be "on the condition that Charlotte go to the party with him."

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence, but it's definitely hard to parse. A more fluent version might replace "on the condition that"  with "if," and "instead of on the condition that" with "even if" and a negative.

Yesterday, James said he might go to the party **if** it is free. Today he said he might go **if** Charlotte goes with him, **even if** it is **not** free.

Answer (score -2):

The example given is technically correct, but very irregular and unnecessarily long-winded. However, removing the rest of the sentence after *instead* doesn't quite work here. By removing the *of on the condition* part, the focus shifts from James' party attendance condition to Charlotte's plans. Taking that sentence:

> Today, however, he says that he may go to the party on the condition that Charlotte goes to the party with him instead.

This suggests that Charlotte was already planning to go to the party with someone else, or that Charlotte has other plans that she would go to instead of the party.

The way I would write this sentence while acknowledging the change in condition would be as follows:

> Today, however, he says that he may go to the party on the condition that Charlotte goes to the party with him, **regardless of whether the party is free of charge or not**.

This shows that for James if Charlotte goes with him to the party, he doesn't care if it's free.

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote this. The original may be wordy, but it's not irregular. Your first rewrite doesn't say "the party is free of charge" like the OP wanted, and the "instead" should be moved closer to the verb it is modifying to avoid confusion. The second rewrite is also wordy. "Regardless of whether" never requires "or not." I don't think either of your solutions is a substantial improvement over the original.

Comment: In the original sentence "instead" goes with the 2nd "on the condition" clause. If that clause is removed, so should the "instead". Leaving it alone at the end of the sentence changes the meaning significantly.